# IPad Chrome Google Colab notebook how to get rid of keyboard icon in cell

Tags: google-chrome, ipad, google-colaboratory, google-chrome-app, ipados

Using iPad Pro 2020 and google chrome app (using desktop site), Colab notebook has a big fat keyboard icon on every cell. How to get rid of it? I got a hardware keyboard for the iPad and absolutely don’t need that icon, it is wasting precious real estate. See screenshot

[image]

Comment: On top of this, cut/paste doesnt work (apple magic keyboard). i think this is an even bigger inconvenience.